# Is there a way to figure out whether some Windows application is capturing screen

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Currently I have C# application, which utilizes SetWindowDisplayAffinity, which supposed to prevent selected windows from capturing via blacking them out. However, looks like according to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2de54518-2f96-439c-aa3e-4d30a1960864/setwindowdisplayaffinity-bug?forum=windowssdk) there are some earlier versions of Windows which have a bug in this mechanism.

So, is it possible to detect that currently something is capturing screen via pinvoke or some other way in order to black out my windows manually without calling system API?

Comment: In a time and age where smartphones with high resolution cameras are a common thing ... do you _really_ think this is worth the hassle?

Comment: rule of thumb: if the user can view it, the user can copy it. it's just a matter of how much effort _you_ want to invest to force the user to invest effort on their own.

Comment: The simpler approach would be to confirm the version(s) that do make this work, and blacklist your application from running on unsupported versions, telling the user to please upgrade/update. You can't expect to build better mechanisms at evading screen capture yourself than what's already built into the OS, even if those mechanisms aren't airtight either -- you don't get to interact with the display driver/compositor directly, unlike the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API that would allow you to determine, whether a process is capturing (part of) the screen.

Capturing the screen is just a sequence of regular API calls, and the system will not keep track of which processes use them in a way that would allow them to capture screen contents. Indeed, it cannot. Capturing screen contents is not a state, but an event.

The feature you are using is not a security feature. As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity):

> It is important to note that **unlike a security feature** or an implementation of Digital Rights Management (DRM), there is **no guarantee** that using SetWindowDisplayAffinity [...] will **strictly protect** windowed content, for example where someone takes a photograph of the screen.